# Alternate colors on only visible details in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress, alternate

I have the following formula in my suppress records formula:

```
if {status.code} in ['1LS','2LS','3LS','PCA','BIR','BTS','CCC','COD','FAC','IAP','IBP',
  'IND','INF','INP','INR','ISN','LOC','LS2','MIN','NAR','NAU','PPL','RSR','RTS','SLD',
  'SSP','SUS','UPD'] then
    true
else
    false;
```

Then in my coloring formula I have the classic:

```
If RecordNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then 
    crSilver 
else
    crNoColoR
```

The problem is the coloring is not alternating because it's referencing all status codes not just the visible. Any thoughts on how to get just the visible ones to alternate coloring?

Comment: Why not just eliminate those status codes from the report?

Answer (score 0):

In-built special field `RecordNumber` will give your the fetched record number from database regardless of whether it's suppressed or not. You can create your own record counter for visible records only and then colorize based on that counter.

1. Create a *Formula Field* `ff_MyRecNo` and set its value in conjunction with your record suppression formula as:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   if {status.code} in ['1LS','2LS','3LS','PCA','BIR','BTS','CCC','COD','FAC','IAP','IBP',
     'IND','INF','INP','INR','ISN','LOC','LS2','MIN','NAR','NAU','PPL','RSR','RTS','SLD',
     'SSP','SUS','UPD'] then 
       // ignore suppressed records
   else
       // count other records
       numberVar recNo := recNo + 1;
   ```
2. Place `ff_MyRecNo` in the *Details* section and suppress it.
3. Change your alternate coloring formula to:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   if {@ff_MyRecNo} mod 2 = 0 then
       crSilver
   else
       crNocolor
   ```